# Test if a value is missing from column range

Tags: excel

I need to write an if statement that tests a column for values that are missing.

So,

```
Categories   | Monday     | Tuesday     | Wednesday     | Thursday     | Friday
Category 1   | F I        |             |               |              |          
Category 2   |            | F I         |               |              | F        
Category 3   | L          |             |  I            |              |          
Category 4   |            |             |               | F            | I        

MISSING      |            | L           | F             | L            | L        
FREQUENCY    | F I        | F I L       | F I           | F L          | F I L
```

> Values in the "MISSING" row need to update to show what values are NOT present in the column above, based on the values in the "FREQUENCY" row.

I've tried COUNTIFS and the REPT approach outlined here: [r/excel: Never use nested ifs again!](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2slys1/never_use_nested_ifs_again/), but the TRUE or FALSE check that both of these rely on seems to fall down when I've tried to apply it in practice.

Is there a simpler method to check against missing values? That is, a formula that in the MISSING row checks what values are in the FREQUENCY row and displays which aren't present in the Column above?

Comment: In the "missing" row you want to show the values which were not used in the column among the values "F", "I" & "L"?

Comment: what letters can be missing?  ie what are you checking to see is there?    Are the F, I and L the only values that might appear as Ani Menon asked?

Comment: ok I think I get it now,  took a bit of head scratching.  You want to test if the frequencies provided at the bottom of the column are found in any of the categories for the same column.  The question still stands though are F, I and L  the only possible frequencies?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified - yep, F or I or L are the only possible values.

Comment: Could the table be reformatted?  Make each day of the week 3 thin columns?  in each column you place the Frequency letters F I and L.  Then life gets a lot cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TRIM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$8)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$2:B$5)))=0,"F "," ")," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("I",B$8)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("I",B$2:B$5)))=0,"I "," ")," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("L",B$8)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("L",B$2:B$5)))=0,"L "," ")," "))
```

I was trying to get all the logic for one letter working inside the sumproduct but my brain is not functioning tonight.  Instead I did a nest if statement.  then I copied that nest 2 times, once for each additional letter.  I brought it all together in one string by placing & between the if statements.  finally in case of extra spaces which could result of not found letters I put the whole thing in a trim statement.

So this is the part that your are really repeating once for each letter

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$8)),IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$2:B$5)))=0,"F "," ")," ")
```

This part is checking to see if the letter is actually being searched for.  If it finds it in the list, it will return a number, and if it does not it returns an error.  That is why its has the ISNUMBER().  So if its a number we know we are searing for it.

```
ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$8))
```

If we are searching for the letter we jump into the next part to determine if the letter is in the column above.  each time it finds one it adds 1 to the total.  so we make it test to see if it finds none which would mean the total is 0.

```
SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("F",B$2:B$5)))
```

You can see we check if the total is 0 and if so we return the "F " with a space after it.  That way it wont be right up against the next found letter.

So once you have that process down, just repeat it for the next letter you want to check and separate the nest IF with & which adds the strings together so "F "&"I " becomes "F I ".  The trim function removes excess non printing characters and leaves 1 space between words.

Now this will work and can be copied across rows and columns...just be aware of cells to lock with $.  I am also sure you can do it all with one if statement and sumproduct but I could not figure it out.

## Update 1

If you can reformat you data to layout in three columns under each day of the week.  One column for each frequency you are testing for.  See image below:

[image: Potential layout]

One possible equation that avoid if statements, as per your linked post, can be placed in B7 and copied to the right.

=REPT(B8,ISERROR(MATCH(B8,B2:B5,0)))

Not sure if that qualifies as a cleaner approach or not.

Comment: Solid gold, that's got it. Thanks very much. I'm amazed there's not a more elegant solution, though...?

Comment: I am sure there is a more elegant solution...its 3AM here and my mind turned off several hours ago!   I also tinkered with an ARRAY formula but they were not quite working like I wanted to either.  I am sure someone will give you an array solution as well.  I now have to go check out the solution to my how to reverse the order of an array question and wrap my head around that one.